# alphanet.sh client list rejected blocks returns Unrecognized Command

Tags: docker

My node is stuck, and I'm trying to find if there are invalid blocks, but the command is unrecognized:

```
root@tezos-public ./alphanet.sh client list rejected blocks
Error:
  Unrecognized command.
  Did you mean one of the following?
```

However, I can run other commands:

```
root@tezos-public ./alphanet.sh client list known addresses
bob: tz1....
alice: tz1...
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Update: I have noticed it should be `tezos-admin-client`, but in `alphanet.sh` I don't see any mention to that. Should I execute the command somewhere else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following command:

```
./alphanet.sh admin-client list rejected blocks
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's exactly what I needed.

Comment: Also, if a block was tagged invalid (because an error like 'No space left on device' for instance) but is actually in the main chain, you can unmark is as invalid using the following: `./alphanet.sh admin-client unmark invalid <block_hash>`